# Is this a correct proof for a span?

Tags: linear-algebra

$V = P_2(\mathbb{R})$ with degree less than 3. Let

$$U = \{f \in V \mid f(2) = 0\} $$

So to prove that$ (t^2-4,t-2) .$ is a basis. Could I do this?

Let $a_1(t^2-4)$ +$ a_2(t-2) $ = $a^2t +bt +c$ and then make a,b and c subjects of $a_1$ and $a_2$ and therefore for any a,b and c you have a combination

Comment: Yes, this seems correct.

Comment: Do you want a basis for $V$ or for $U$?

Comment: Sorry, I want a basis for $U$

Comment: I think you want $(x-2)^2$ not $x^2-4$

Comment: Why did the indeterminate $t$ turned to $x$ in the last part of your post?

Comment: Sorry, my error! Using two different indeterminates!

Comment: What difference would factorising make?

Comment: Also do not forget to check/state the basis is *free*, i.e. there is only one way to write $a_1$ and $a_2$ according to $a$,$b$,$c$.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Would I have to substitute t=2 into the right hand side?

Comment: What is the answer for this question?

Comment: @PaxKivimae: Either choice works for making a basis.

Comment: You can try to solve for $a_1$ and $a_2$. But note that on the right-hand side we don't want general $at^2+bt+c$, since the polynomial on the right is $0$ at $2$. Maybe work with $at^2+bt-4a-2b$.

Comment: @Andre Nicolas Okay! So if I solve my original equation = to $at^2 +bt-4a-2b$ and solve for $a_1$ and $a_2$ I have my answer?

Comment: Yes, that will do it. That has been done by egreg. You can also do it without mentioning matrices.

Comment: You also need to show linear independence for a basis.

Answer (score 1):

It's true that any linear combination of $t^2-4$ and $t-2$ is an element of $U$, but you have to prove also the converse.

So, let $at^2+bt+c\in U$; you want to show that $at^2+bt+c=a_1(t^2-4)+a_2(t-2)$ has a solution, which is possibly what you mean in the last paragraph.

The equations become
\begin{cases}
a_1=a\\
a_2=b\\
-4a_1-2a_2=c
\end{cases}
and the linear system has the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & a\\
0 & 1 & b\\
-4 & -2 & c
\end{bmatrix}
$$
A row echelon form for this matrix is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & a\\
0 & 1 & b\\
0 & 0 & 4a+2b+c
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Since the polynomial belongs to $U$, we have $4a+2b+c=0$ and so the system has *unique* solution. Therefore the two vectors form a basis.

Answer (score 0):

First show that $t^2 - 4 \in U, t-2 \in U$, which are both clear.

Then show that these are linearly independent, which shouldn't be too hard.

Suppose that $f(t) = at^2 + bt + c$ is in $U$. So 2 is a root of $f$. This means $f(t)$ is divisible by $(t-2)$, so $f(t) = p(t)(t-2)$ where $p(t)$ is linear at most.

Write $p(t) = d(t+2) + e$ (which can be done for any linear $p(t)$. Then $$f(t) = (t-2)(d(t+2) + e) = d(t^2 - 4) + e(t-2)$$

This shows that the two polynomials span $U$.